Cannot read an audio file (wav) on Safari
I am currently implementing a next js app that display an audio player.
Really simple use case : I am fetching a wav file from Supabase Storage.
1- I am fetching the audio file :
const fetchAudio = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(url);

  const blob = await res.blob();
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  setBlobURL(blobURL);
};
fetchAudio();

2- I am using this blob in my html audio element
<audio>
  <source src={blobURL} type="audio/wav" />
</audio>

But I cannot get something working.
Here is a screenshot of my network :

When I log my blob everything seems fine, and I have the correct mime-type, same for the created URL, everything looks good..
Safari is up to date.
Try to load the url from supabase directly
